# Nginx-proxy doesn't forward to container exposing port 3001 and rewrites URL to static IP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, nginx, proxy, docker-compose

I got a web application running on Ruby on Rails with SOLR in docker-compose. It exposes port 3001, and I want a subdomain URL than my university possesses (and I have access to the configuration panel where I can only specify the "target", what is the IP, I guess, of my local server on which the web application is running).

I first tried to do this redirection without nginx, but the URL data.chembiosys.de was just redirected to http://static.ip:3001
The app is running though, and is accessible.

So I wanted to try to use nginx as a reverse proxy, but the effect is basically the same:
- I need to specify the port number and the IP of my server in the configuration panel of the domain name of interest
- when I type "data.chembiosys.de" in the browser, it shows the IP and the port number

What I do is that I first create a nginx-proxy network:

```
sudo docker network create nginx-proxy
```

Then I start nginx-proxy with docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - /home/myhome/Projects/nginx-proxy/conf/my_conf.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/my_proxy.conf:ro

  whoami:
    image: jwilder/whoami
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=whoami.local

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

In the second volume, I copy to the nginx-proxy container the following config file:

```
server {
    listen 80; 
    server_name http://mystaticip:3001;
    client_max_body_size 2G;
    return 301 http://data.chembiosys.de$request_uri;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host data.chembiosys.de;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass         http://mystaticip:3001;
    }
}
```

And finally, I run the rails app docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:


  db: 
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: seek-mysql_cbs
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - docker/db.env
    volumes:
      - seek-mysql-db_cbs:/var/lib/mysql

  seek: # The SEEK application
    #build: .
    image: fairdom/seek:1.7
    container_name: seek_cbs
    command: docker/entrypoint.sh
    restart: always
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: production
      SOLR_PORT: 8983
      NO_ENTRYPOINT_WORKERS: 1
    env_file:
      - docker/db.env
    volumes:
      - seek-filestore_cbs:/seek/filestore
      - seek-cache_cbs:/seek/tmp/cache
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - solr
    links:
      - db
      - solr

  seek_workers: # The SEEK delayed job workers
      #build: .
      image: fairdom/seek:1.7
      container_name: seek-workers_cbs
      command: docker/start_workers.sh
      restart: always
      environment:
        RAILS_ENV: production
        SOLR_PORT: 8983
      env_file:
        - docker/db.env
      volumes:
        - seek-filestore_cbs:/seek/filestore
        - seek-cache_cbs:/seek/tmp/cache
      depends_on:
        - db
        - solr
      links:
        - db
        - solr

  solr:
    image: fairdom/seek-solr
    container_name: seek-solr_cbs
    volumes:
      - seek-solr-data_cbs:/opt/solr/server/solr/seek/data
    restart: always



volumes:
  seek-filestore_cbs:
    driver: local-persist
    driver_opts:
      mountpoint: /home/myhome/Projects/ChemBioSys/docker_volumes/seek-filestore_cbs
  seek-mysql-db_cbs:
    driver: local-persist
    driver_opts:
      mountpoint: /home/myhome/Projects/ChemBioSys/docker_volumes/seek-mysql-db_cbs
  seek-solr-data_cbs:
    driver: local-persist
    driver_opts:
      mountpoint: /home/myhome/Projects/ChemBioSys/docker_volumes/seek-solr-data_cbs
  seek-cache_cbs:
    driver: local-persist
    driver_opts:
      mountpoint: /home/myhome/Projects/ChemBioSys/docker_volumes/seek-cache_cbs

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

I have the feeling that nginx-proxy is just failing to connect the URL to the app. What an I doing wrong and how to connect the app to the URL with nginx? And also, how to avoid the rewrite of the URL to the IP:port?

P.S. The static IP I got from the SysAdmins is alphanumerical and I see the following warning when the nginx-proxy docker-compose runs:

```
nginx-proxy    | [warn] 30#30: server name "http://pc08.ian.uni-jena.de:3001" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/conf.d/my_proxy.conf:3
```

Comment: After quick glance looks like Nginx conf is the problem. Remove 'return' line and change server_name to data.chembiosys.de

Comment: I just tried this, but the problem is still the same
- the URL is not forwarded to the correct port
- and the URL is rewritten to the static IP of my server